# Angular JS 1.5 - Using Observable RXJS in two components

Tags: angularjs, rxjs

I'm using AngularJs 1.5. I am using ng-route to create a SPA. For 2 templates I have used the new Angular component as the template let's call them 'employee' and 'company'. Within each route there is a sub component that searches the company database call it companySrch. How the sub component works is the companySrch component is loaded in either 'company' or 'employee' when the user want's to search the company database within that template. When the user selects a record in the search results, the record is broadcast through a registered RXJS observable as follows:

```
companySrch.getRecordFn = function(result){
            companySrch.output={id:result.cs_id, type:result.type,name:result.name, active: result.active};
            //BROADCAST RECORD SELECTED via companySrchService
            companySrch.companySrchService.recordBroadcast(companySrch.output); 
            companySrch.navService.nav.navExt = false;
}
```

Then if the user is in employee or company template, that record is passed through the template's subscription to the RXJS event. Example for both templates employee and company respectively:

```
employee.companySrchService.subscribe(function(obj) {//SELECTRECORD IS PASSED VAR FROM BROADCAST FUNCTION
            //GET COMPANY RECORD UPON BROADCAST
            employee.submit[0].cs_name = obj.name;
            employee.submit[0].cs_type = obj.type;
            employee.submit[0].fk_cs_id = obj.id;
            //employee.getRecordFn(obj.id); 
        });

company.companySrchService.subscribe(function(obj) {//SELECTRECORD IS PASSED VAR FROM BROADCAST FUNCTION
        //GET COMPANY RECORD UPON BROADCAST
        company.getRecordFn(obj.id); 
    });
```

The issue I have when I am in the employee template and a companySrch record is broadcast the subscribed event also is fired in the 'company' on the assumption I have previously loaded the company template. As such this causing an error. I thought components are killed completely when templates are switched?? Is there any way I can prevent the RXJS subscribe event from occurring if the template is not in view??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can create a Subject that will emit as soon as the directive's `$destroy` event is triggered.

```
var destroy$ = new Rx.Subject();
$scope.$on('$destroy', () => destroy$.onNext());
```

And we can update the stream that we subscribe to so that we stop emitting items as soon as `destroy$` emits once:

```
company.companySrchService
    .takeUntil(destroy$)
    .subscribe(function(obj) {
        company.getRecordFn(obj.id); 
    });
```

This will cause your subscription callback to stop firing as soon as the `$destroy` event occurs.

Comment: Thanks Calvin almost works, but the event for $on needs to be $destroy not $delete. If you update the above I will vote it up and tick it :)

Comment: also the following $delete in $scope needs to be edited to $scope.$on('$destroy', function(){ //etc...});   :)

Comment: Hi Calvin after fully testing this I get a console error Rx.ObjectDisposedError {message: "Object has been disposed"} when I try to open the company template. The dispose method seems to destroy the whole subscription subject where I only want the current template to stop subscribing upon changing templates (ie when it is destroyed). Any advice on this?

Comment: Gonna have to think about it; running out of the house now though.

Comment: Hi @Ka Tech, I took a different approach. See my edited post.

Comment: Thanks Calvin I tried it I actually get an error takeUntil is not a function.

Comment: @KaTech I assumed `companySrchService` was an observable; to get this to work, you will need to expose the underlying observable.

Comment: I got it now, but the issue I see with this is when company or employee is destroyed this would again stop the subcription service for both components. I only want the subscription to stop when a component is no longer in view (eg company destroyed and employee in view). To be honest I've searched and search and the only easy fix would be to have a separate subject in companySrchService for employee and company. This way I make a broadcast to the relevent subject based on the component it is opened in. I appreciate your persistence, thanks again.